# How can I explain the difference in decision boundary and its reason in relation to the dimension of the hidden layer?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, classification, perceptron

I got these 3 different plots of decision boundaries using 3 different parameters for hidden_layer_sizes of the MLPClassifier from sklearn on XOR gate.

```
xor_data = np.array([[0, 0], [1, 0], [0, 1], [1, 1]])
xor_labels = np.array([0, 1, 1, 0])
```

```
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier
mlp1 = MLPClassifier()
mlp1.fit(xor_data, xor_labels)
print("Score:", mlp1.score(xor_data, xor_labels))
plot_decision_boundary(mlp1, xor_data, xor_labels, "Perceptron on XOR")
```

[image]

```
mlp2 = MLPClassifier(hidden_layer_sizes = (300, 200, 100))
mlp2.fit(xor_data, xor_labels)
print("Score:", mlp2.score(xor_data, xor_labels))
plot_decision_boundary(mlp2, xor_data, xor_labels, "Perceptron on XOR")
```

[image]

```
mlp3 = MLPClassifier(hidden_layer_sizes = (10))
mlp3.fit(xor_data, xor_labels)
print("Score:", mlp3.score(xor_data, xor_labels))
plot_decision_boundary(mlp3, xor_data, xor_labels, "Perceptron on XOR")
```

[image]

How can I explain the difference in decision boundary and its reason in relation to the dimension of the hidden layer?

I just simply thought that higher dimension lead to smoother and more accurate classification and decision boundary, but I think there must be a better explanation that this so I want some help.